# create point and then get simple bearing and distance to point possible in mapbox mobile app?

Tags: navigation, mapbox

I am working with a contractor that is building us a mobile mapping app for iOS and Android devices. We would like to add some navigation capabilities for backcountry exploration, in particular, a simple "goto" point or polygon tool that would allow a user to tap on a point or polygon on the map and then get a bear and distance to the point, start navigation, and keep track of progress on bearing and distance as the hiker moves through the back country. Is this possible and can someone share an example that I can then share with our contractor to see how this could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this certainly sounds possible. I don't have an example which does exactly that, but some pieces which might be helpful are this example to display user location on a map, https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/tracking-mode/, and Turf to calculate bearing and distance https://github.com/mapbox/turf-swift. That's in iOS, similar approaches can be used in Android as well.